# Where is Startup Disk Creator installed?

Tags: software-center

Using XFCE.

I installed usb-creator, also called Startup Disk Creator using the Ubuntu software center. Where is this installed? It does not show up anywhere in the menu. In the terminal I've tried different commands like usb-creator-common, usb-creator-kde, etc. Program can not be found.

I like Linux, but this is one of those things that I think is just really sad in Linux or more specifically Ubuntu. If the software centre does not even tell you what the executable name is and where it's stored, how the hell does it expect the user to locate the application?

I suppose I could check the various bin-folders, but the executable names are sometimes unclear as to their nature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know the name of the package, you can list all of it's files using `dpkg -L package`:

```
$ dpkg -L usb-creator-gtk
/usr/bin/usb-creator-gtk
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/usbcreator/frontends/gtk/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/usbcreator/frontends/gtk/frontend.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/usbcreator/frontends/gtk/unitysupport.py
/usr/share/applications/usb-creator-gtk.desktop
/usr/share/doc/usb-creator-gtk/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/usb-creator-gtk/copyright
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/usb-creator-gtk.svg
/usr/share/man/man8/usb-creator-gtk.8.gz
/usr/share/usb-creator/usbcreator-gtk.ui
```

In this case the binary is called `/usr/bin/usb-creator-gtk`

Answer (score 3):

If you use the (ubuntu supported) Software Center with the (Ubuntu supported) Unity, you will have it in the Dash. One of the good things of Linux is the flexibility; so you are free to use a different desktop environment (like myself). But it is not fair to whine about your freedom...

You can list all the file installed by a package using

```
dpkg-query -L <package>
```

And doing

```
 dpkg-query -L <package> | grep bin
```

has a very high probability to give you the answer. Happy Linuxing!

Maybe you have just installed the common package without any graphic front-end; try to install the package that will work in XFCE (I do not know if it's the `-gtk` one or the `-kde` one, probably the first with `sudo apt-get install usb-creator-gtk`)

Comment: This is not directly an answer to the question, but worth +1 nevertheless. Give a man a fish, y... you know.

Answer (score 1):

For me, using Gnome, it is located as `/usr/bin/usb-creator-gtk`.

Answer (score 1):

**There is not a single place where the files are installed**

To start **Startup Disk Creator** press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and execute `usb-creator-gtk`

To know where are the configuration files execute these commands:

```
whereis usb-creator-gtk
```

also

```
dpkg -L usb-creator-gtk
```

Hope you will get your answer.

Comment: usb-creator-common, -gnome, -kde, -gtk, doesn' work. Says program is not installed.

Comment: @ShrimpCrackers: Check my answer, once again.. What does `sudo dpkg -l | grep usb-creator` and `whereis usb-creator-gtk` return you? I'm also using XFCE, have you tried to find it in **Application Finder**? Reply..